# Ensuring file follows style guides

Tags: javascript, node.js, formatting, format, prettier

So I'm looking for a way to take eslint or prettier or one of the other linters / formatters to check files for adhering to a style guide that we have.

I have seen plenty of examples of running prettier or eslint against files you have in your project, but what I am looking to do is given an outside filename is given from the command line or otherwise, run prettier or eslint against it, not to format the file but to tell me any places where the file breaks the style guide.

I have been doing a lot of research but not finding much. I think I saw that you can run prettier from the command line so I think could fake it by doing `exec` to simulate the command line.

However, I would prefer a more direct approach like importing a prettier or eslint package or something.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Running `eslint --ext js,jsx src/ --fix` will run eslint against all `*.js` and `*.jsx` files in the `src` directory, automatically fix what it can, and report back what it cannot.  Running `eslint --ext js,jsx src/  will run eslint against all `*.js` and `*.jsx` files in the `src` directory and simply report back the warnings/errors.  Running `eslint src/index.js  will run eslint against `src/index.js`and simply report back the warnings/errors.

Comment: Most places hook it up to their build or commits to their source control.

Comment: So if you have `eslint` installed globally, you can just run it as `eslint <path-to-your-file>` and it will report back any warnings or errors it finds, and if it finds nothing it will exit.  If you have it installed only as part of your project, you can do the same but use the path in `node_modules`: `node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js path/to/your-file.js`.  You can also hook it into pre-commit hooks or build processes.

Comment: So what I'm understanding here is that the only way to go is to run `eslint` using `exec` to get me a report of the files?